# Using External jQuery and JSON not working

Tags: jquery, json, getscript

I am looking to create multiple html files for each phone-brand with a common '.js' file and '.json' file. I am trying to replace the word ‘Brand’ in the common '.js' file with the respective brand name each time and get the respective data from the '.json' file.

I am using a separate '.js' and '.json' file residing in the same folder as my html file. Then using the ‘text.replace’ command in each html file, I’m trying to get the relevant data from my JSON file through the common '.js' file.

My html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="GetLocalJSON.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<style>
</style>

<body>
    <div id="AboutTab">
        <div id=About>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

var url = "GetLocalJSON.js";
$.getScript( url, function() {
  $(document.body).find('Brand').each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    $(this).text(text.replace('Brand', 'Samsung')); 
  });

});

});
</script>
</html>
```

My GetLocalJSON.js jQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var StatJSON;
        jQuery.getJSON("QueryJSONData2.json", function (json) {
            StatJSON = json;

    var markup = '';
    markup += '<div>'+ StatJSON.Phone.Brand[0].Size +'<div>'
    
$("#About").html(markup)
});
});
```

My QueryJSONData2.json JSON file:

```
{
    "Phone": {
        "Samsung":[{
          "Size" : "AAA",
          "Camera" : "BBB",
          "Weight" : "CCC"
        }],
        "Apple":[{
            "Size" : "XXX",
            "Camera" : "YYY",
            "Weight" : "ZZZ"
          }]

    }

}
```

The error I am getting is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" at the line :

```
markup += '<div>'+ StatJSON.Phone.Brand[0].Size +'<div>'
```

which means my "text.replace" jquery command is not being action-ed. How do I fix this???

Comment: Not sure why you have included jQuery twice?

Comment: You should probably keep a single HTML page and JavaScript and maybe use a URL search `?brand=Samsung` then query the URL search parameters and then use that value in the JS

Comment: Hi @phuzi, as mentioned, there is a common '.js' file and '.json' file I intend to use across multiple html files, with only 'brand' replaced eachtime. Could you please elaborate the code you are suggesting?

Answer (score 0):

Your `QueryJSONData2.json` is having no property named `Brand` inside `Phone` object.

So, `StatJSON.Phone.Brand[0].Size` will break, since your `Replace` jquery command will have no impact on your `StatJSON` object.

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve using replace, but I am guessing if you want to replace `Samsung` with `Brand`, then you should do it inside your `GetLocalJSON.js` file.

One possible transformation is shown below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var StatJSON;
        jQuery.getJSON("QueryJSONData2.json", function (json) {
            StatJSON = json;

    var markup = '';

    //transform data to add all brands inside phone object
    var brands = []
    Object.keys(StatJSON.Phone).forEach(item => {
      brands.push(StatJSON.Phone[item]);
      delete StatJSON.Phone[item];
    });
   StatJSON.Phone.Brand = brands;
    
   markup += '<div>'+ StatJSON.Phone.Brand[0].Size +'<div>'
    
$("#About").html(markup)
});
});
```

Make sure you have transformed your data correctly, before you use it in your HTML.

This should give you some direction to fix it.

Comment: Hi Abhinav, Thanks for the quick reply. I tried applying your suggested solution but it did not work. I am very sorry, but my question was probably not clear to begin with. I am looking to create multiple html files for each brand with a common .js file and .json file. I am trying to replace the word 'Brand' in the common .js file with the respective brand name each time and get the respective data from the '.json' file. I hope this clarifies the issue. Once again, thanks for the reply and looking forward to your second reply. :)